# Java Font Usage Project Error

Tags: java, fonts

So I'm doing this project to display certain fonts.
The problem is that The original code works
But When I try to use a scanner it doesn't

**Original Code**

```
 public static void main(String[]args)
{
font("Times New Roman");
}

public static void font(String x){
World canvas = new World();//Creates a new world called canvas
Graphics picGraphics = canvas.getGraphics();//creates picGraphics which gets used in the world
picGraphics.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);//Color is set to Magenta
Font font = new Font(x,Font.BOLD,80);
picGraphics.setFont(font);//sets the font
//drawString parameters tell the string that is written and the coordinates to place the word
picGraphics.drawString("Font Tester",105,255);
canvas.repaint();
}
```

Now with the code with the scanner

```
public static void font2(){
World canvas = new World();//Creates a new world called canvas
Graphics picGraphics = canvas.getGraphics();//creates picGraphics which gets used in the world
picGraphics.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);//Color is set to Magenta
Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
String x = keyboard.next();
Font font = new Font(x,Font.BOLD,80);
picGraphics.setFont(font);//sets the font
//drawString parameters tell the string that is written and the coordinates to place the word
picGraphics.drawString("Font Tester",105,255);
canvas.repaint();
}
```

As you see with that code I have a scanner so that the user can directly input the font they want into the program to be displayed. However whenever I use that new code with an example such as Time New Roman the font that displays in the window is not even Times new Roman but more like Arial...
I have also tried putting the scanner in the main method which also doesn't give any different of a result

Help?

BTW: A lot of preset code has been added already so that codes such as World canvas = new World(); and other bits will help with the display of the pop up blank window where i can display the fonts

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Scanner.next` method is returning only the first word of your input, which would be `Times`, and the system can't find a font with that name.

You can use the `nextLine` method to read an entire line with whitespace between the words:

```
String x = keyboard.nextLine();
```